# How to check if JSON object is empty in Java?

Tags: java, json, isnull

In Java, if I use the following `JSON` string as an example, how would I check if the objects are **empty/null**?

```
{"null_object_1" : [], "null_object_2" : [null] }
```

**I have tried using:**

```
if(!jsonSource.isNull("null_object_1"))  {/*null_object_1 is not empty/null*/}
if(!jsonSource.isNull("null_object_2"))  {/*null_object_2 is not empty/null*/}
```

But these `IF` statements still return true (as if they are not empty/null).

Does anyone have a solution?

**Edit:**
By "object", I actually meant `array`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neither of those two things are `null`; they are arrays. The result is exactly what you would expect.

One of your arrays is empty, the other contains a single element that is `null`.

If you want to know if an array is empty, you would need to get the array, then check its length.

```
JSONObject myJsonObject = 
    new JSONObject("{\"null_object_1\":[],\"null_object_2\":[null]}");

if (myJsonObject.getJSONArray("null_object_1").length() == 0) {
    ... 
}
```

**Edit to clarify:** An array having no elements (empty) and an array that has an element that is `null` are *completely different things*. In the case of your second array it is neither `null` nor empty. As I mentioned it is an array that has a single element which is `null`. If you are interesting in determining if that is the case, you would need to get the array then iterate through it testing each element to see if it were `null` and acting upon the results accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Java's null (: I'm too used to working with PHP (where checking for null usually goes for both empty and null).

Comment: Glad I could help. Honestly, IMHO I would avoid using `null` for this reason. In Java `null` has a special meaning that does not equate to `0` or "empty" - it can only be assigned to object reference variables and indicates that the variable has no object reference assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

As per this documentation [JSONObject API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29), `isNull` checks for value NULL, which is not true in your case.

If 'null_object_1' value is String, you need to use String `temp = getString("keyName")` and check

```
!("".equals(temp));
```